# How to create multi module project with separate event bus in GWT, Maven.?

Tags: maven, gwt, module, multi-module, event-bus

I'm working on a GWT project but stuck with a situation where I have to create 2 different modules with separate eventBus in the same project. One module should be child of another i.e. there should be some way to invoke or load child module from a main module eventBus.

I tried it with by looking at this link https://code.google.com/archive/p/mvp4g/wikis/MultiModules.wiki#Before,_After but giving some differed binding exceptions.

Can someone please elaborate the  detailed procedure to get the solution.?

Comment: Parent module with under it a service module containing the event bus and its services. Both modules using the event bus are also children of that parent module.

Comment: How can we differentiate parent and children module or how can we bind child module with the parent.?

Comment: With maven you can just specify child modules in the parent pom.xml. GWT has its own structure and I don't know exactly how that would look.